# Hyperbolic surface subgroups of products of groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory

I am an undergraduate student, currently working in an REU project about geometric group theory. I know a few basic notions of geometric group theory and algebraic topology: Cayley graphs, fundamental groups (of topological spaces and of graphs of groups), Seifert-van Kampen theorem, classification of compact 2-manifolds, ...

While reading the following article: [Surface subgroups of Coxeter and Artin groups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002240490300207X?via%3Dihub); I encountered the following questions.

**Question.**

1. If the direct product $A\times B$ of two groups $A$, $B$ contains a hyperbolic surface subgroup, then either $A$ or $B$ contains a hyperbolic surface subgroup.
2. If the free product $A*B$ of two groups $A$, $B$ contains a hyperbolic surface subgroup, then either $A$ or $B$ contains a hyperbolic surface subgroup.

Here, a *hyperbolic surface group* means a fundamental group of a closed, compact $2$-manifold with genus $g >1$, which can be presented as $\langle a_1, b_1, \ldots, a_g, b_g \hspace{0.1cm}|\hspace{0.1cm} [a_1, b_1][a_2, b_2]\cdots [a_g, b_g] = 1\rangle$.

The article that I am reading claims that this is "trivial", however, I do not know how to prove these results. Please give me hints or ideas to prove the above claims. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your background? How much geometric group theory do you know? Both claims are indeed trivial if you have a sufficient background.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Dear Kohan, I am an undergraduate student, currently working in a REU project about geometric group theory. I know a few basic notions of geometric group theory and algebraic topology: Cayley graphs, fundamental groups (of topological spaces and of graphs of groups), Seifert-van Kampen theorem, classification of compact 2-manifolds, ...

Comment: Let me suggest that (to avoid close votes) you edit your post in order to give at least [a little bit of context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), for example: some details from your comment; the source of this article; perhaps a bit about your own thoughts regarding a proof.

Comment: Your link is broken. I've edited in a new link.

Comment: OK, do you know that fundamental groups of surfaces do not split as nontrivial free products? Do you know that two elements of a hyperbolic surface group commute iff they generate a cyclic subgroup?

Comment: I do not know these results beforehand. Can you recommend some books related to this topic so that I can learn more? Thank you!

Comment: You can start by reading [here](https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/on-subgroups-of-surface-groups/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group with the property that the centralizer of every conjugacy class $\neq\{1\}$ is trivial (example: $G$ negatively curved surface group).

Then $G$ has the following property: whenever $G\subset A\times B$, $G$ projects injectively into either $A$ or $B$ (indeed the kernels of two projections are normal subgroups of $G$ centralizing each other...

(The free product case was already addressed in comments, using that negatively curved surface groups don't split into nontrivial free products.)